# The availability of lsblk on RHEL 5

Tags: rhel, lsblk

According to the following solution link
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2063833, there is no lsblk on RHEL 5.

Could it be said that there is no solution for lsblk on RHEL 5?

Comment: The webpage needs login. But can't you just compile the code to get `lsblk` ?

Comment: The util-linux-2.19 could compiled successfully on RHEL 5.5,  but executed with a segmentation fault！